# Deploying an app on AWS that is an Instagram replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have few doubts in my planning stage for my new venture:

I am trying to deploy an app on AWS that is an Instagram replica where people will be posting their pictures online.

Which AWS service would:

- recommend to store images? S3?
- end customers use to download these images?
- be used to retrieve image data like comments and tags?
- be used to transform images to small sizes? CloudFront?
- be used to search through all the images and tags?
- be used to frontend all API requests ?

I also want to store videos in S3 for fast retrieval under heavy load, so is it fine to organize videos like folders for easy access like `key=folder1/folder2/folder3/video.mp4` or would it be a good idea to create a random hash of 10 for the keyname or may be a hash of 20 followed by a logical name?

Comment: Your question is too broad for a standard answer on StackOverflow. It is preferred that you have a specific question, tell us what you've tried and what problems you've had, and ask for assistance in solving that particular issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your question is too broad for an answer on StackOverflow, here's an attempt at a response...

While certain AWS services can be used to build an Instagram-like application, you'll still have to do A LOT of coding. AWS makes it easy to store data, manage and serve your data, the application still needs to be written by you.

To answer your questions:

- **Storing images:** Definitely **Amazon S3**. It can store as many files as you wish.
- **Downloading images:** Just embed URLs in web pages and **S3** will serve the images to your users. You can even use **pre-signed URLs** to provide private content to authorized users.
- **Comments and tags:** While limited metadata can be associated with objects stored in Amazon S3, it would be better for your application to store this type of data in a database. The database could be launched under **Amazon RDS** (Relational Database Service).
- **Transform image sizes:** Your application would be responsible for doing this. However, you could use 3rd-party services to automatically transform images, such as [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/), [lib-pixel](https://libpixel.com/) and [imgix](https://www.imgix.com/).
- **Searching through images and tags:** This would be the responsibility of your application, but it would be aided by use of a database and you could consider **Amazon Cloudsearch**, which is actually [used by SmugMug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lgl7EKaFv1Y) for this purpose.
- **API front-end:** Use **Amazon API Gateway** to act as a front-end to API requests, but your application would be responsible for fulfilling those requests.
- **Retrieving videos under heavy load:** Store the videos in **Amazon S3** but use **Amazon CloudFront** to serve the videos. It can cache content closer to your users and knows how to serve video content to web browsers. Filename strategies will not impact the speed of serving content, so name the files however you wish.

Comment: Thanks John for the detailed explanation... One last query..                          3> Which AWS service would you use to retrieve image data like comments and tags > For this can Amazon SQS be used as well ?

Comment: Amazon SQS is a queuing service, where messages are sent to a queue, then retrieved from a queue. It would not be used to "retrieve image data like comments and tags". It is typically used to store some work for later processing (eg if there are many videos to process, put them in a queue and process each one in turn when a server is available).